# Considering the letters STUVWXYZ, how many strings can be formed with the letters Y, U, T and S appearing in that order but not necessarily together?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Considering the letters STUVWXYZ, how many strings can be formed with the letters Y, U, T and S appearing in that order but not necessarily together?

Comment: With or without repetition?

Comment: If without repetition: $\binom{8}{4} \times 4! = 1680$

Comment: Thanks very much. It would have been without repetition.

Answer (score 2):

First, place Y, U, T, S. There will be 8 possible locations in the string $x_1x_2x_3x_4x_5x_6x_7x_8$ to place those letters. In other words, every placement will correspond to a 4-element subset of positions chosen from the set $\{1, 2, \dots, 8\}$. You probably know that there are $\binom{8}{4}$ such subsets.

Having done that, we're left with 4 positions, say $i_1, i_2, i_3, i_4$, into which we have to place the remaining letters, V, W, X, Z. We have 4 choices for the letter in place $i_1$. Having filled that slot, there are 3 letters that can go in position $i_2$, then 2 remaining letters to go in position $i_3$ and of course only one letter to place in position $i_4$. The total number of arrrangements, then, will be
$$
\binom{8}{4}\cdot4\cdot3\cdot2\cdot1
$$
as Quixotic indicated.